# Resolved SQLBulkCopy - The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm getting that error when running my SSIS package at night. The weird thing is it doesn't fail for every table, it fails for a few 5-12 from 60 tables. Another thing is that tables that are failing could be different daily. At night when running reconciliation I use only 2 columns ID and CreatedDate and I'm 99% sure that the columns are identical.

An interesting fact is I have 2 servers and this SSIS is running on both. It fails only on Production and on my test server everything is OK. Tables and columns on both servers are identical, Table Names and Types.

Errors I'm getting:

- Main:Error: Error : column ID Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 1. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError (SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
- Main:Error: Error : The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.AnalyzeTargetAndCreateUpdateBulkCommand(BulkCopySimpleResultSetinternalResults)

I must be missing something here, but at this stage, I'm lost.

Many thanks for any advice

**RESOLVED**

**CAUSE**
In code, I was creating a temp table where data is recorded using SQLBulcCopy and turns out that these tables must mix with each other.

**SOLUTION**
For each table, I need to create unique temporary table names that stop confusion in the system.

Comment: Might as well make it 100% and verify *everything* matches with the columns coming from SSIS: data types, length/scale/precision, nullability, collation, and check names are matching case-sensitive

Comment: From SSIS I pass String and Datetime to Varchar and DateTime in MS SQL. I think there are no issues in types or names as names are Uppercase because the same table can pass today, fail tomorrow and be OK the next day. A number of tables are failing is different from day to day. If there is some issue as you suggest the same tables will fail every day, and is not a case :(

Comment: Not necessarily: it might be a collation issue which only affects certain values. Or it might be a mismatched type where some values can be converted and others not, for example `varchar` and `datetime`